# Manually verify S/MIME message digest

Tags: openssl

Like [described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567623/how-to-see-what-attributes-are-signed-inside-pkcs7/24581628#24581628), I tried the following steps:

1. Save signed e-mail and extract p7s-part to `Test.p7s`
2. `$ openssl asn1parse -in Test.p7s` gives me:
   [image]
3. `$ dd if=Test.p7s of=Test.bin bs=1 count=677 skip=4557`
4. `$ openssl asn1parse -in Test.bin` results in:

---

```
  0:d=0  hl=2 l=  87 prim: priv [ 5 ]        
  Error in encoding
  140297479046808:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding    routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:asn1_lib.c:157:
```

---

All I want to do is check if the message digest matches the hash which would be created width

`$ openssl dgst -sha256 < mail.txt` for example.

Comment: To extract and/or separately look at the signedattrs in that example you need to first convert from base64 to binary and then copy from offset 4557 for the length of the header PLUS the length of the contents 4+677=681 and then handle the result as binary aka 'der' not base64 aka 'pem'. But that doesn't actually help with verifying the digest, about which you have multiple other Qs open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> openssl smime -sign -in index.xml -out index.cms  -inkey ./certs/Sign_Key.key -signer ./certs/Sign_Key.crt

openssl smime -verify -in index.cms -CAfile ./certs/Sign_Key.crt -out index.csm.xml

> openssl dgst -binary -sha256 index.xml  | openssl base64